# How Chronicle Wire allows you to serialize and deserialize objects with higher performance

Tags: low-latency, chronicle

We would be developing a low-latency market data solution for which we are exploring Chronicle products.

Quoting from [article](https://chronicle.software/high-performance-java-serialisation-to-different-formats/)

> Chronicle Wire allows you to serialize and deserialize objects to and
> from binary format, and also to a lot of different formats at the same
> time as it has higher performance than Java standard serialization.

I would like to have more information on this. Spl would love to understand what is done by implementing net.openhft.chronicle.wire.Marshallable makes Wire-based serialization much faster than java serialization and backward-compatible.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Wire does the following;

- it supports trees and not graphs, ie no circular references
- doesn't use reflection, which is relatively slow
- supports serialization and deserialization without creating objects
- uses a binary format with a low overhead directly to/from off-heap memory without needing an extra copy